# How to deal with infinite output of python cmd call?

Tags: python, cmd, process, pycodestyle

sometimes i need to call a cmd within my python programm and would like to parse the output. In most cases, the cmd call performs it's action, prints a couple of lines and terminates.
Unfortunately, some cmd commands seem to never terminate and to keep printing blank lines. Therefore i started counting the lines read and simply stop at some point. Example code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE
from subprocess import STDOUT

command = ["gcc", "-v"]

try:
    process = Popen(command, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

    if process.returncode:
        print("Cmd command {} was spawned successfully, yet an error occuring during the execution of the command".format(command))

    lineCounter = 0
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
         if(lineCounter < 50):
             print(line)
             lineCounter += 1
         else:
             break

except Exception as exceptionError:
     print("Command {} can't be started. Error message: {}".format(command, exceptionError))
```

While "gcc -v" actually terminates, some other commands i ran into  did not. Is there a more elegant and stable way to solve this?
I read some suggestions to stop parsing after a certain amount of time instead of lines, but that also seems kind of dirty to me.

Comment: Can you give an example of such command? From my experience, commands producing infinite output tend to be system monitoring tools which dump **current** values of certain parameters at constant intervals. I can't remember any command that produces useful output followed by inifinite number of blank lines…

Comment: @Błotosmętek "svn info" is one example

Comment: Never happened to me. In general your solution is good, though for this particular case you could try breaking the loop not after a given number of lines, but rather after a given number of **identical** lines – see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
lineCounter = 0
prevLine = ''
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
     print(line)
     if line == prevLine:
         lineCounter += 1
         if lineCounter > 50:
             break
     else:
         prevLine = line
         lineCounter = 0
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation with your code-only answer?

Comment: The explanation is in a comment to the question. Do you think it should be repeated in the answer?

Comment: That make the code better and more ugly at the same time. Not the answer i was hoping for but its a really good and appreciated workaround. Thanks a lot :)